# update an angular model using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How do I get $scope.animal to update when clicking the radio button?

http://plnkr.co/edit/5ikIYfXQw4GyjRKScD7x?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.animals = {
    dog: {
      label: "Dog"
    },
    cat: {
      label: "Cat"
    },
    bird: {
      label: 'Bird'
    }
  };

  $scope.animal = 'dog';
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in animals">
        <label>
          {{val.label}}
          <input type="radio" name="animal" value="{{key}}" ng-model="animal">  
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Animal: {{animal}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

When you click the radio button, it should say the name of the animal you just clicked on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ngRepeat` creates a different scope, you can either use `$parent`

```
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="{{key}}" ng-model="$parent.animal">
```

or use an object:

```
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="{{key}}" ng-model="animal.name">
```

#### Controller:

```
$scope.animal = {
    name : "dog"
};
```

Comment: Hevery's rule: "Wherever there's an `ng-model` there got to be a `.`" (... I'm pretty sure it was him :P)